# is it possible when user will click download button the file will be downloaded in the temp folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net-2010

Is it possible in ASP.net to force the client browser to save a file in temp folder?
Like when user clicks download button and the file is downloaded in the temp folder.

Comment: You cannot control how the browser downloads a file.

Comment: But how??
Ive asked for the solution if any one can help

Comment: Cant i use temp folder? isnt it a part of Browsers sand box?

Answer (score 1):

you mean force client's browser to download a file to a specific folder? -

short answer: no.

long answer: ***due to security issues you cannot force client's browser do anything that might compromise client's machine***. therefore the browser will only download files to where client told it to. its not up to you.

Comment: Cant i use temp folder? isnt it a part of Browsers sand box?

Comment: you cannot download a file to client's machine automatically. browser only download's page-related files like pictures and stuff, but if its an external file, the browser will decide what to do with it. its not up to you, sorry.